# Custom theme and content view for dialog, which one is the winner?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am confused about something. Lets say that you create a custom theme for a dialog.
Also, you create custom Content View.

now if you create  a dialog with that theme and the custom content view, which one takes precedence?
In other words, if the color of the TextView in the theme is black and in the content view, your views have textfields with red color, what would be the resulting dialog showing?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you go on and try it yourself..

Comment: i expected someone to tell me that. Well Thats why I am asking, incase someone has tried (or know the answer) and can share the knowledge for me and everyone else